# Z-INDEX e BOX-SHADOW

Tags: html, css

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
<style>

.all{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background:url(images/background.jpg);
}
header{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    display:inline-block;
    background:url(images/bordatopo.png) top repeat-x;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
.header-center{
    width:60%;/*1200px*/
    margin:0 auto;
    height:auto;
    max-height:229px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.logo{
    float: left;
    width: 35%;
    margin-bottom:15px;
}
.logo img{
    width:100%;
    /*padding:0 15px 15px 15px;*/
}
.menu {
    float: left;
    width: 65%;
}
.menu ul {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 1em;
    margin-top: 6em;
}
.menu li {
    font-size: 1.2em;
    margin:0 0 1em 2em;
    display: inline-block;
}
.menu li a {
    color: #8c7265;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family:"Futura Medium";
    font-size:.8em;
}

.sombra{
    position:relative;
}
.sombra:before,.sombra:after{
    z-index:-1;
    position:absolute;
    content:"";
    bottom:15px;
    left:10px;
    width:50%;
    top:80%;
    max-width:300px;
    background:#777;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 15px 10px #777;
    -moz-box-shadow:0 15px 10px #777;
    box-shadow:0 15px 10px #777;
    -webkit-transform:rotate(-3deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(-3deg);
    -o-transform:rotate(-3deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(-3deg);
    transform:rotate(-3deg);
}
.sombra:after{
    -webkit-transform:rotate(3deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(3deg);
    -o-transform:rotate(3deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(3deg);
    transform:rotate(3deg);
    right:10px;
    left:auto;
}

</style>
    <header>
        <div class="header-center">
            <div class="logo sombra">
                <img src="images/logo2.png" alt="" width="100%">
            </div>
            <nav class="menu">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#produtos">Produtos</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#chadebebe">Chá de Bebe</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#contato">Contato</a></li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="">
                            <img src="images/icon_email.png" height="20" />
                        </a>
                        <a href="">
                            <img src="images/icon_fb.png" height="20" />
                        </a>
                        <a href="">
                            <img src="images/icon_insta.png" height="20" />
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria que o background do header ficasse por cima da logo,
e que a sombra da logo apareça, que por algum motivo ela não está sendo exibida.

Comment: Não consegui reproduzir aqui. Se possível crie um [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) com o código funcionando e inclua na pergunta.

Comment: Ponha seus códigos para funcionarem em tempo de execução, como bem disse o @renan.

Answer (score 1):

Eu acredito que você deve alterar o seu codigo CSS:

```
header{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    display:inline-block;
    background:url(images/bordatopo.png) top repeat-x;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    z-index:999;
}

.logo img{
    z-index:-1;
    width:100%;
}
```

Para a sombra aparecer, tente tirar os pseudo seletores `:before` e `:after`.

Mas conforme o renan mencionou nos comentários, tente adicionar um jsfiddle para facilitar.